# Почему возникает ошибка ECONNREFUSED при работе Node.js с MySQL на localhost?

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-modules

```
const mysql = require("mysql2");

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  database: "usersdb",
  password: "123"
});

connection.connect(function(err){
    if (err) {
      return console.error("Ошибка: " + err.message);
    }
 });

 connection.end(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log("Ошибка: " + err.message);
  }
});
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "mongoapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.0",
    "express": "^4.16.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.1.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.8.0",
    "mysql2": "^2.0.2"
  }
}
```

На `localhost` под windows 10 получаю  `"Ошибка: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306"`, это же пишет в лог.

Вариантов решения проблемы на SO не нашел. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю неправильно и как это исправить.

Comment: А mysql-то вообще запущен? В вопросе про это ни слова. И если да, то какие сетевые интерфейсы он слушает?

Comment: Мне очень стыдно, но не был запущен. Благодаря вашему вопросу я это выяснил. Спасибо за реакцию!